# Instantiating generic type ArrayList<T>

Tags: java, generics

I am new to generics and read in a article "A parameterized type, such as `ArrayList<T>`, is not instantiable — we cannot create instances of them".

Full quote, from Java in a Nutshell:

> A parameterized type, such as `ArrayList<T>`, is not instantiable - we
>   cannot create instances of them. This is because `<T>` is just a type
>   parameter - merely a place-holder for a genuine type. It is only when
>   we provide a concrete value for the type parameter, (e.g.,
>   `ArrayList<String>`), that the type becomes fully formed and we can
>   create objects of that type.
>
> This poses a problem if the type that we want to work with is unknown
>   at compile time. Fortunately, the Java type system is able to
>   accommodate this concept. It does so by having an explicit concept of
>   the unknown type which is represented as `<?>`.

I understand that it should not be instantiable since the concrete (actual) type is not known. If so, why does the below code compiles without an error?

```
public class SampleTest {

    public static <T> List<T> getList(T... elements) {

        List<T> lst = new ArrayList<>(); // shouldn't this line return an error? 

        return lst;
    }
}
```

I know there is a gap in my understanding of generics here. Can someone point out what am i missing here?

Comment: "A parameterized type, such as ArrayList, is not instantiable" => What book does state that? It's wrong! Of course you can instantiate those classes. Why not? What meaning would they have otherwards?

Comment: *A parameterized type, such as ArrayList, is not instantiable—we cannot create instances of them* can you show the code for this statement ?

Comment: Regarding the question on your commented line, the compiler uses inference to figure out what type should be in the diamond.  You may also list that type explicitly if you want.

Comment: Can you add the reference of that phrase? It's not correct...

Comment: @Leviand I did it

Comment: @Leviand - This phrase is from a book "Java in Nutshell" , the whole phrase is below <br/>
Wildcards
A parameterized type, such as ArrayList<T>, is not instantiable—we cannot create instances of them. This is because <T> is just a type parameter—merely a placeholder for a genuine type. It is only when we provide a concrete value for the type parameter, (e.g., ArrayList<String>), that the type becomes fully formed and we can create objects of that type.

Comment: @seeker27 This is something called _type erasure_, which happens during compilation, by which `ArrayList<String>` ends up just being `ArrayList` of `Object`.  Generics are there to provide _compile_ type safety, e.g. to prevent you from accidentally putting something into a `List<String>` which is not actually a `String`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks it makes sense now, the statement from the book somehow confused me

Comment: The shown method `getList` compiles but it shifts the need to provide a concrete type for the generic parameter `T` to the caller of this method. Since `T` is a method parameter of `getList` it has to be provided by the caller.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen while you are right, type erasure does not completely erases generics. Think about it: suppose I have a class that has a method `public void testMe(List<Integer> list){...}` - I compile it and give it to you. Will you be able to call it with `List.of("abc")` for example? just compile any generic class and look at two things `descriptor` and `Signature`

Comment: @Eugene You're right; I've never thought in this way.  Again, the Oracle trails don't really delve into this level.  Maybe a good topic for another question ^ ^.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen if you post one, I would be glad to share my thoughts on it... ping me if you do

Comment: To get the full context of that quote, see https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/java-in-a/9781449371296/ch04.html. I think the book should say "`A parameterized type, such as ArrayList<T>, is not instantiable unless T is defined as a class, interface or enum, or a previously instantiated type parameter.`"

Comment: @LuCio: "but it shifts the need to provide a concrete type for the generic parameter T to the caller of this method. Since T is a method parameter of getList it has to be provided by the caller." The caller doesn't actually "provide" anything at runtime, and the compiler when compiling this method doesn't know what code may call this method; it just verifies that the code works no matter what `T` is. Also, this method would compile perfectly fine even if you removed all the parameters -- the method does not need to be passed anything with `T` in it.

Comment: @newacct  It seems you got me wrong. Please note: I didn't mentioned _runtime_ in any word. Thus type erasure and anything at runtime goes beyond my comment. But while you're syntactically right saying "his method would compile perfectly fine even if you removed all the parameters" this means to use raw type. The compiler would issue warnings. That's not my understanding of "compile perfectly fine". That would be even worse and should be avoided. My intent was to make clear that `T` is a method parameter and as such _should_ be passed implicitly or explicitly to the method by the caller.

Comment: @LuCio: "this means to use raw type. The compiler would issue warnings." Wrong. There is no raw type involved at all. No warnings. When this method is compiled, the compiler does not know that there is a caller, or care about callers at all. It just cares that the method is legal as declared. Code that calls this method could be compiled at a later time against this method signature. It doesn't matter. When compiling this method, it does not know anything about `T`; by declaring a generic method with type parameter `T` with no bound, it promises that it is legal no matter what `T` is.

Comment: @LuCio: I think you are using your terminology wrong. `T` is a "type parameter" declared by this generic method. `T` is a type and is not a "parameter" of this method. The only parameter is the variable named `elements`, and you can remove that and the method would be perfectly legal generics, with no raw types, and the method can instantiate `new ArrayList<T>()` absolutely fine.

Comment: @LuCio: It's unclear what you mean by the need to "provide" a concrete type is shifted to the caller in your comment. As I mentioned, nothing is "provided" at runtime. Can a caller "provide" something at compile time if the caller is compiled later, separately from the called method? See, it doesn't make sense either way. Whether a caller's code is legal is checked against the type signature of the called method when the caller is compiled, and in some sense the compiler checks that the call has a valid type witness, but this has nothing to do with the semantics of the called method.

Comment: @newacct You're right about my wrong terminology Yes, I meant `T` is a _type parameter_. And when saying "provide" I meant _pass in_. I checked the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) for the right terminology. I should have done it before to prevent this confusion.

Comment: Reading you [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52604138/instantiating-generic-type-arraylistt#comment92830548_52604138) I understood, I got your first comment wrong. You said "even if you removed all the parameters", you said not "type parameters". But I was thinking of type parameters and therefore mentioned raw type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that you mention can compile because the Object "lst" is not actually initialized until the method is called. Since the method knows that it will be getting a var-args argument of type T, it can compile in this scenario. Take the example Wrapper class below for example:

```
public class Wrapper<T> {


    public static <T> List<T> getList(T... elements){
        List<T> lst = new ArrayList<>();
        for(T element: elements) {
            lst.add(element);
        }
        return lst;
}
```

}

This code can compile because the method hasn't been called. When the method is called, Type T will be the type that we pass as the var-args argument and the code will have no issue compiling. Lets test this in our main method:

```
 public static void main( String[] args ){

      System.out.println(Wrapper.getList("Hi", "Hello", "Yo"));

 }
```

And the output is:

```
[Hi, Hello, Yo]
```

However, lets generate a compile-time error to see what the article is talking about within our main method:

```
Wrapper<T> myWrap = new Wrapper<>();
```

We are actually trying initialize a generic Object of the Wrapper class in the code above, but  is unknown. Since the value for the placeholder  will be unknown even when we call the method, it results in a compile-time error, whereas creating a List of type T within the getList method does not cause a compile-time error because it will be initialized with a type when the method is called.

Comment: "Since the method knows that it will be getting a var-args argument of type T, it can compile in this scenario." The method does not know anything about `T` at runtime. And it is perfectly fine for the method to create and return an `ArrayList<T>` even when the method doesn't take any arguments of type `T` at all: `public static <T> List<T> getList(){
        List<T> lst = new ArrayList<>();
        return lst;
}`

Answer (score 4):

Because `T` is given as another generic type argument.

It's the whole purpose of generics to make the type parameterizeable. So the caller can specify the type. This can be done in multiple layers: the caller may also be generic and let its caller specify the type.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  foo(7);
}

public static <T> void foo(T value)
{
  bar(value);
}

public static <U> void bar(U value)
{
  baz(value);
}

public static <V> void baz(V value)
{
  System.out.println(value.getClass().getSimpleName());
}
```

It prints out

```
Integer
```

> A parameterized type, such as `ArrayList<T>`, is not instantiable

Means: You cannot create ArrayList of an unknown T. It must be specified at compile time. But it can be done indirectly, by another generic. In your case, it's **another** `T`, which will be specified again by the caller of your generic `getList`.

---

The wildcard `<?>` is something different. It is used to specify compatibility. `<?>` is the syntax to avoid specification of the type. You can use `extends` to require a basetype or interface. However, you cannot create instances with wildcards.

```
  List<?> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

This wouldn't be possible otherwise. It makes most sense when using it in parameter specifications, for instance:

```
  public static int foo(List<? extends Comparable> list)
  {
     return list.get(1).compareTo(list.get(2));
  }
```

It's very confusing of this book. It assumes that `<?>` somehow solves the problem that a `List` with unknown `T` cannot be instantiated. IMHO, this is rubbish. T must be specified to create an instance.

Comment: I would have given you a +1 if you had not stated "Means: when you reach this point at runtime" - parameterized types are only looked at during compile time. At runtime, they're all Object, due to _type erasure_. Also, `Foo`, `Bar` etc. should start with small letters by Java convention; `Main` should be `main(String[] args)` (otherwise it's just not a main method); and `object` should be `Object`. I appreciate you're coming from C# where your answer would have been correct in that language.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException: Thanks for the feedback. Fixed a few things. You're right with the runtime argument. I wasn't sure how to say it correctly. I just remove this sentences, they were not even required for the point. Would be great if you had some feedback to the `<?>` part. I'm not sure if I got that correctly.

Comment: Completely rephrased the wildcard `<?>` part.

Answer (score 0):

once you call the method -> you are using a concrete value.

the method defines T and later you use it in the return type and the parameter list.

```
public static <T> List<T> getList(T... elements)
```

once you will send the first parameter from specific type -> the contract will force you for the next parameters.

`List<? extends Object> list = getList("", 1);` -> in this case java doesnt find common between string and integer so it uses the most basic connection "Object"

`List<String> list2 = getList("test", "test2");` -> here you can see that because all of the parameters are Strings - java find that in common and use it as the T.

Answer (score 0):

The specific passage from the book doesn't make any sense and is wrong. `new ArrayList<T>()` is perfectly fine provided that we are in the scope of a type parameter named `T` (either a type parameter of a generic class that we are in, or a type parameter of the generic method we are in).

`new ArrayList<T>()` can no less be instantiated than `new ArrayList<String>()` -- both compile to the same bytecode and both just instantiate an `ArrayList` object at runtime. The object doesn't know anything about its type parameter at runtime, and therefore no knowledge of `T` at runtime is needed to instantiate it. The type parameter in an instantiation expression of a parameterized type (`new ArrayList<T>`) is just used by the compiler to type-check the parameters passed to the constructor (there are none in this case) and to figure out the type returned by the expression; it is not used in any other way.

And by the way the method does not need to receive any parameters of type `T`, or of any type containing `T`, in order for this to work. A method that receives *no arguments* can still instantiate and return an `ArrayList<T>` perfectly fine:

```
public static <T> List<T> emptyList() {
    List<T> lst = new ArrayList<T>();
    return lst;
}
```

Also, the section in the book where this statement appears in doesn't really have anything to do with instantiation -- the section is about wildcards, and wildcards don't really have anything to do with object instantiation at all. So I am not really sure why they are mentioning it (incorrectly) there.